# How to add a class to element that contains current URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a global table that will contain several url's and are trying to add a class to the ones that matches the current website url but got stuck. Anyone that could give me a hint?

I've gotten closest with jQuery, it works with text but not with a variable.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var url = window.location.href; 
      $("tr:contains(url)").addClass('active');
    });

</script>
```

HTML

```
<table id="press" class="press1">
 <thead>
  <tr class="row-1">
    <th class="column-1">day</th>
    <th class="column-2">month</th>
    <th class="column-3">time</th>
    <th class="column-4">place</th>
    <th class="column-5">production</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="row-hover">
  <tr class="row-2">
    <td class="column-1">10</td>
    <td class="column-2">oktober</td>
    <td class="column-3">18:00-19:00</td>
    <td class="column-4">place</td>
    <td class="column-5"><a href="http://link.se/production1">production name 1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-3">
    <td class="column-1">11</td>
    <td class="column-2">december</td>
    <td class="column-3">18:00-19:00</td>
    <td class="column-4">place</td>
    <td class="column-5"><a href="http://link.se/production2">production name 2</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-3">
    <td class="column-1">22</td>
    <td class="column-2">december</td>
    <td class="column-3">18:00-19:00</td>
    <td class="column-4">place</td>
    <td class="column-5"><a href="http://link.se/production3">production name 3</a></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please add table element code too

Comment: Could you add the HTML structure as well?

Answer (score 1):

The [`:contains()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) only matches elements that contain specific *text*. To match the value of an element's attribute (e.g. `href`), use the [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

> **attributeEquals selector**
>   Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.
>
> ```
> jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )
> ```

Also see other [attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):
[contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `*=`, [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `^=` , [not equal](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) `!=`, etc.

---

In your case, we want to add a class to `<tr>` elements that contain an `<a>` with a specific `href` value.

One method is to use the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

> **has selector**
>   Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.
>
> ```
> jQuery( ":has(selector)" )
> ```

```js
let url = window.location.href;

$(function() {
  $('tr:has(a[href="' + url + '"])').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td><a href="https://example.com/">Example</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="https://stacksnippets.net/js">This Page</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="https://example.com/">Another Example</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Another method is to select the `<a>` element and then [traverse](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) up to the appropriate `<tr>`.

```js
let url = window.location.href;

$(function() {
  $('a[href="' + url + '"]').closest('tr').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td><a href="https://example.com/">Example</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="https://stacksnippets.net/js">This Page</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="https://example.com/">Another Example</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`url` is not evaluated in your selector as you expect; you're actually looking for any table row containing the text "url".

Instead, do something like:

```
$("tr:contains(" + url + ")").addClass('active');
```

Depending on your data you may need to worry about escaping it but this should get you started at least.